# CSS problem: Combination of "text-align: center" and "min-width" not working in IE 7/IE 8 compat mode

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    input.navbutton
    {
        text-align: center;
        min-width: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" class="navbutton " value="Next" />
</body>
</html>
```

On IE 7, this ends up looking like this:

[image]

But on Firefox it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text is not correctly centered in IE 7.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Bumped into the same problem today. Can't find a reasonably acceptable solution... have you?

Comment: Adding `line-height` seems to work. See my answer below for a full example.

Answer (score 2):

`min-width` on a button already doesn't work in IE6/7 (it won't expand the button at all when the text is larger, as you seem to expect). Replace it by `width` and live with it.

Comment: min-width is supported by IE 7 (not IE 6), but appearantly it is a bit buggy. The behavior is correct in IE 8 (non-compat mode)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530820(VS.85).aspx

Comment: D'oh. I literally said `min-width` **on a button**. Try and see yourself before headlessly downvoting :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
input.navbutton
{
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
    align:center;
}
```

In IE (old), `align` affects the text too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dice I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Nice bug your caught there einarq..

It could be related to the min-width bug : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/e54188ad-cdad-4168-bbf9-2d0b5271676d

The only viable workaround i can see is to drop the min-width and add left and right paddings ..

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure it out, but I finally got it. A combination of three properties need to be used:

```
input.navbutton {
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    line-height: 120%;
}
```

Your text will be centered automatically. `line-height` can be excluded if you're aligning your text to the left or right. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4mw3zhL/) for a full example.

[image: Example shown in IE7]

Answer (score 0):

this was a big problem for me but I've got a solution

```
input.navbutton
{
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

adding auto will turn the text back to place.

it worked for me on IE

Answer (score -1):

Try `margin: 0 auto;` in your CSS.  I know this centers text for `<div>` tags but I don't know about buttons.

Answer (score -1):

try changing you CSS to this:

```
    input.navbutton
    {
            text-align: center;
            min-width: 100px;
    }
```